# Why do I not see "Store" in the project menu for my Windows Phone 8.0 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone, appx

According to official guide - i have to build a .appxupload file via special Wizard. Unfortunately, i simply don't have the option "Store" in Project menu. I only have "test Store" with opportunities to test my app's icons, XAP-file, etc.. Can anyone help with this stupid situation? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Windows Phone **8.0** apps are packaged in **.xap** files.
- Windows Phone **8.1** apps are packaged in **.appx/.appxupload** files.

Your app is an 8.0 app so your app will be packaged in a .xap file which is generated when you build the app using the mode `Release`.

If you want to output a `.appx` file you'll need to do the following:

1. Get `Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RTM`
2. **Convert your 8.0 app to an 8.1 app**
3. Right-click the project and go to `Store -> Create App Packages...`